# How to draw 3D Pie charts in Android

Tags: android, 3d, pie-chart

Is there any easy way to draw 3D style pie charts in Android?. I know some people draw 3D style pie charts using Path and some mathematics. But it is really difficult to manange.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: You can pay a look to some libraries here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517624/3d-charts-libraries-in-android. Not all are 3D but maybe can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Orson Charts for Android](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html) (commercial, as in not free) can do this for you very easily.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of graphing threads on SO #Android - this was one of the more active ones:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156740/im-looking-for-fancy-charts-library-for-android/5157576#5157576

The one I'm talking about in there, Steema TeeChart, recently released their beta. I am currently using that and I can **definitely** recommend it: http://steema.com/entry/60 The library gives you access to a ton of things and it's made by some really professional guys.

It will not be free when the final release rolls around though. For free alternatives, see the thread I linked.

Comment: Well, I am looking free library, that can work for fancy pie chart (3D style). Most of sample shows normal charts. It can be draw fancy chart using trigonometry mathamatics, but difficult to manage.

Comment: I sincerely doubt you will find any library more advanced than Steema's for Android at this point. And yes, it does 3D.