# 3D charts libraries in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Here I am looking for how to display 3D charts in webview. Currently I am using aChartEngine library i.e. 2D chart library but now for upgradation, I want to use 3D charts .. So I am looking for some 3rd party libraries for showing 3D charts...(either paid or free).. Can anyone pls help me on this..Please provide me the list of 3D charts 3rd party libraries

The chart that I am looking for should look like:

[image]

Comment: I think this Question can be answered by your self also just after doing some "googling". Sorry If I am wrong.

Comment: see http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/samples/aicharts/sample-viewer.aspx?sample=piesample

Comment: @MKJParekh: Yes I am doing Research on It, but not getting anything specific...I have listed some of the libraries but want to know more so that I can Implement the best way..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done lot of research in collecting several types of charts in android...
these are some of them.....

### Java related charts

1. J4L charts
2. artful bits charts
3. steema charts
4. afreecharts
5. android plot
6. achart engine charts

Using Javascript charts are build .
Below i have mentioned them

1. mcharts
2. opengl
3. fusion charts
   ...
   like this you can have many more building charts using javascript

Comment: Orson Charts 3D is a commercial library now available on Android, the demo app is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orsoncharts.android.demo

Answer (score 2):

http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html 
Orson Charts 3D is a commercial library now available on Android, the demo app is here:

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking - there is [NChart3D](http://nchart3d.com/nchart-android/). That's commercial library, implemented in C++ and fully wrapped in Java.